# Spring JSP variable not assigned

Tags: spring, jsp, jsp-tags

I have in my JSP page code like this:

```
<spring:url value="" var="url"/>
<a href="<c:url value="/change_locale?locale=EN&current=${url}" />">EN</a>
```

And issue is that parameter url in link is always set to empty String.I would expect that if I type url like localhost:8080/test the url variable will hold this value and it will be replaced in link so it would look like /change_locale?locale=EN&current=test. However it is always generated like /change_locale?locale=EN&current=.What I am doing wrong? Best regards

Comment: I'm confused. What do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
<spring:url value="" var="url"/>
```

Your `value` value is the empty `String`. Because of this, the URL is relative.

Spring uses [`UrlTag`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html) to construct the value from a `<url>` tag. You'll want to take a look at its `createUrl` method in the source code if you're curious.

In this case, it will generate a value that is the empty `String` and store it in a page scope attribute named `url`. That's what you get when rendering

```
${url}
```

Comment: If I set value to empty in spring:url then link to current page is generated. For example I I type http://localhost:8080/test the spring:url is generating http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: @John Can you run with what you have above and post the HTML source code from the rendered page?

Comment: Sorry You were right. It is working because it sets value to empty String so thats why this current url work. Thanks for clarifying this. I need something different to obtain current url.

Comment: @John Look into the `HttpServletRequest` methods. The `url` tags are for building urls.